# Delete non-empty directory in Racket programming language

Tags: racket

How to delete a non-empty directory in Racket?

When I invoked this api `(delete-directory dir)`, in which `dir` is `"/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/aoi"`, I was told that:

```
exn found:#(struct:exn:fail:filesystem:errno delete-directory: cannot delete directory
  path: /Users/apple/Library/Application Support/aoi
  system error: Directory not empty; errno=66 #<continuation-mark-set> (66 . posix))
```

For context, this is the rest of my code:

```
(define lib-folder '("/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/aoi"))
(define (del-lib-folder)
  (for-each (λ (p)
              (printf "del lib folder:~a~n" p)
              (if (directory-exists? p)
                  (delete-directory p)
                  (printf "folder does not exist:~a~n" p)))
            lib-folder))
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in many operating systems the command to delete a directory only works if the directory is empty. Eg. in GNU

```
# rmdir dir
rmdir: failed to remove 'dir/': Directory not empty
```

Usually a recursive delete is needed:

```
# rm -r dir
#
```

In `#lang racket` you have the function [`delete-directory/files`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=delete-directory#(def._((lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt)._delete-directory%2Ffiles))) that deletes recursively. Just replacing `delete-directory` with `delete-directory/files` would do what you want:

```scm
(define lib-folder '("/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/aoi"))
(define (del-lib-folder)
  (for-each (λ (p)
              (printf "del lib folder:~a~n" p)
              (if (directory-exists? p)
                  (delete-directory/files p)
                  (printf "folder does not exist:~a~n" p)))
            lib-folder))
```

Be very careful though as a bug in the file list will do exactly as you asked and you may never get those files back.

Answer (score 0):

use delete-directory/files:

```
(define lib-folder '("/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/aoi"))
(define (del-lib-folder)
(for-each (λ (p)
          (printf "del lib folder:~a~n" p)
          (delete-directory/files #:must-exist? #f p))
        lib-folder))
```